# How to fix IndexOutOfBoundsException : invalid index 0 size is 0

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am storing the response of `yes|no|maybe` into the `userrelation` table.
For that, I created a table in `DBCONTRACT` and get the values in a `db helper` Class.

when I get the values and store into another variable, it throws this error

This the SQL query for the `userRelation` table

```
 public static abstract class RingeeUserRelationTable implements BaseColumns {

        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "user_relation";
        public static final String COL1_EVENT_USER_ID = "EVENT_USER_ID";
        public static final String COL2_EVENT_ID = "EVENT_ID";
        public static final String COL3_RINGEE_USER_ID = "RINGEE_USER_ID";
        public static final String COL4_IS_ATTENDING = "IS_ATTENDING";
        public static final String COL5_IS_DELETE = "IS_DELETE";

        public static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COL1_EVENT_USER_ID + INTEGER_TYPE + COMMA_SEP + COL2_EVENT_ID + INTEGER_TYPE
                + COMMA_SEP + COL3_RINGEE_USER_ID + INTEGER_TYPE + COMMA_SEP + COL4_IS_ATTENDING + INTEGER_TYPE + COMMA_SEP + COL5_IS_DELETE + INTEGER_TYPE + ")";

        public static final String DELETE_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;

        public static final String RETRIVE_ALL_USER_DATA = "SELECT " + COL1_EVENT_USER_ID + COMMA_SEP + COL2_EVENT_ID + COMMA_SEP + COL3_RINGEE_USER_ID + COMMA_SEP + COL4_IS_ATTENDING + COMMA_SEP
                + COL5_IS_DELETE + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    }
```

This is the code for getting the value and set to `userMOS` list

```
public ArrayList<UserMO> getAllUserRelation() {
        ArrayList<UserMO> userMOs = new ArrayList<UserMO>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(DatabaseContract.RingeeUserRelationTable.RETRIVE_ALL_USER_DATA, null );
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                UserMO userMO = new UserMO();
                userMO.setEventUserId(cursor.getLong(1));
                userMO.setEventId(cursor.getLong(2));
                userMO.setRingeeUserId(cursor.getLong(3));
                userMO.setIsAttending(cursor.getInt(4));
                userMO.setIsDelete(cursor.getInt(5));
                userMOs.add(userMO);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

            cursor.close();
        }
        return userMOs;
    }
```

This is the code for getting the `isattending` value in the Fragment

```
    context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
            dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
            userMOs = dbHelper.getAllUserRelation();
// I got the error here there is no value in a table but in back end the values are stored 
    int  isAttending = userMOs.get(position).getIsAttending();
```

I am using this `isattending` for setting the colour of the `yes|no|maybe` Button

```
  switch(isAttending)
            {
                case 1:
                    yesBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    noBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    maybeBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    yesBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    noBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    maybeBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    break;
                case 0:
                    yesBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    noBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    maybeBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    break;
            }
```

When I run this project, I get an error: IndexOutOfBoundsException.
Please tell me what is the cause of the error and how to solve this issue

Comment: You need to at least narrow it down. Where's the error occur? Otherwise, the easy and obvious answer is "don't go out of bounds!"

Comment: Please do not post irrelevant code. Just post the code which you feel migh t be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Indexes are **0 based**.
Therefore, you need to rewrite your code like so:

```
public ArrayList<UserMO> getAllUserRelation() {
    ArrayList<UserMO> userMOs = new ArrayList<UserMO>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(DatabaseContract.RingeeUserRelationTable.RETRIVE_ALL_USER_DATA, null );
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            UserMO userMO = new UserMO();
            userMO.setEventUserId(cursor.getLong(0));
            userMO.setEventId(cursor.getLong(1));
            userMO.setRingeeUserId(cursor.getLong(2));
            userMO.setIsAttending(cursor.getInt(3));
            userMO.setIsDelete(cursor.getInt(4));
            userMOs.add(userMO);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        cursor.close();
    }
    return userMOs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the following code as shown below:-

```
public ArrayList<UserMO> getAllUserRelation() {
        ArrayList<UserMO> userMOs = new ArrayList<UserMO>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(DatabaseContract.RingeeUserRelationTable.RETRIVE_ALL_USER_DATA, null );
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                UserMO userMO = new UserMO();
                userMO.setEventUserId(cursor.getLong(1));
                userMO.setEventId(cursor.getLong(2));
                userMO.setRingeeUserId(cursor.getLong(3));
                userMO.setIsAttending(cursor.getInt(4));
                userMO.setIsDelete(cursor.getInt(5));
                userMos.add(userMO);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

            cursor.close();
        }
        return userMOs;
    }
```

Its giving you a Array Index out of bound exception as you have not assign anything to your array list. which I had did by adding this line in your code above.

```
userMos.add(userMo);
```

Comment: I don't think your solution is useful.

Comment: Wait until OP provide some useful information for issue or tell OP to post useful  info and then based on that provide a solution. Your current solution is just like `Playing the chess in the dark`

Comment: @MD no I am not, let the OP decide it. And if you think I am playing Chess in the Dark, then I think I just killed your Queen with my Pawn, save your King as its a Check.